# bat equivalent on linux

Tags: android, batch-file, compilation, apk

I have a .bat file which I use to create .apk with it file in my windows...
now I need to be able to create the .apk file in ubuntu but i don't know how translate my bat file to batch file to be able to run it on ubuntu!!!

below is the bat file which works fine on windows... will you please give me some hints on how I can run it on ubuntu?

```
@echo off
set PAUSE_ERRORS=0
:user_configuration

:: Path to Flex SDK 
set FLEX_SDK=C:\sdk\flex_sdk_4.5.1.21328

:: Path to Android SDK
set ANDROID_SDK=C:\sdk\android

:validation
if not exist "%FLEX_SDK%\bin" goto flexsdk
if not exist "%ANDROID_SDK%\platform-tools" goto androidsdk
goto succeed

:validation
if not exist "%FLEX_SDK%\bin" goto flexsdk
if not exist "%ANDROID_SDK%\platform-tools" goto androidsdk
goto succeed

:flexsdk
echo.
echo ERROR: incorrect path to Flex SDK
echo.
if %PAUSE_ERRORS%==1 pause
exit

:androidsdk
echo.
echo ERROR: incorrect path to Android SDK in 'bat\SetupSDK.bat'
echo.

if %PAUSE_ERRORS%==1 pause
exit

:succeed
set PATH=%PATH%;%FLEX_SDK%\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_SDK%\platform-tools

:: Android packaging
set AND_CERT_NAME="PeymanApp"
set AND_CERT_PASS=fd
set AND_CERT_FILE=cert\SampleApp.p12
set AND_ICONS=icons/android

set AND_SIGNING_OPTIONS=-storetype pkcs12 -keystore "%AND_CERT_FILE%" -storepass     %AND_CERT_PASS%

:: Application descriptor
set APP_XML=application.xml

:: Files to package
set APP_DIR=bin
set FILE_OR_DIR=-C %APP_DIR% .

:: Your application ID (must match <id> of Application descriptor)
set APP_ID=air.com.doitflash.SampleApp

:: Output packages
set DIST_PATH=dist
set DIST_NAME=PeymanApp

:validation
%SystemRoot%\System32\find /C "<id>%APP_ID%</id>" "%APP_XML%" > NUL
if errorlevel 1 goto badid
goto end_validation

:badid
echo.
echo ERROR: Application ID (APP_ID) does NOT match Application descriptor '%APP_XML%'     (id)

echo.

:end_validation

set TARGET=
set PLATFORM=android

::call bat\Packager.bat
if "%PLATFORM%"=="android" goto android-config

:android-config
set CERT_FILE=%AND_CERT_FILE%
set SIGNING_OPTIONS=%AND_SIGNING_OPTIONS%
set ICONS=%AND_ICONS%
set DIST_EXT=apk
set TYPE=apk
goto start

:start
if not exist "%CERT_FILE%" goto certificate
:: Output file
set FILE_OR_DIR=%FILE_OR_DIR% -C "%ICONS%" .
if not exist "%DIST_PATH%" md "%DIST_PATH%"
set OUTPUT=%DIST_PATH%\%DIST_NAME%%TARGET%.%DIST_EXT%
:: Package

echo true
echo.
call adt -package -target %TYPE%%TARGET% %OPTIONS% %SIGNING_OPTIONS% "%OUTPUT%"     "%APP_XML%" %FILE_OR_DIR% -extdir lib/
echo.
if errorlevel 1 goto failed
goto end

:certificate
echo Certificate not found: %CERT_FILE%
echo.

if %PAUSE_ERRORS%==1 pause
exit

:failed
echo APK setup creation FAILED.

if %PAUSE_ERRORS%==1 pause
exit

:end
```

Comment: Hello Peyman, Stack Overflow isn't the right kind of site for getting your code translated from one language to another. Try converting it yourself to a shell script (there are tons of books/tutorials out there on this). If you get stuck on specific issues, post here about those.

Answer (score 5):

I would write a bash script. See [this guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)